# Display timer that works out Days, hours, minutes and seconds from a date then increments in real time

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to Display a timer that works out Days, hours, minutes and seconds from a date then increments in real time on a view/page.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: r u looking for like stop watch or count down timer...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this way:-

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
    {
        [self start];
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    }

int currentTime;
- (IBAction)start{

     currentTime = 0;
     lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    //creates and fires timer every second
    myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];
}
- (IBAction)stop{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}

- (IBAction)reset{

    [myTimer invalidate];
    lbl.text = @"00:00:00";
}

-(void)showTime{

    currentTime++; //= [lbl.text intValue];
    //int new = currentTime++;

   int secs = currentTime % 60;
int mins = (currentTime / 60) % 60;
int hour = (currentTime / 3600);
int day =   currentTime / (60 * 60 * 24);

lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2d:%.2d",day,hour, mins, secs];

NSLog(@"my lable == %@",lbl.text);

    NSLog(@"my lable == %@",lbl.text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to read the [*Date and Time Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i) to learn about using the `NSDate`, `NSCalendar`, and `NSDateComponents` classes.

Comment: And use a repeating NSTimer to update the countdown at a regular interval.

Comment: If he wants to show fractions of a second, `CADisplayLink` would be more appropriate.

Comment: just seconds would be ok.. :-)