# display the difference in Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds with it then updating in realtime?

Tags: iphone, ios, date, timer

I am a noob...
I have

```
QuitTime.text = quitDate;
```

Which is a date in the past...
How can I display the difference in Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds with it then updating in realtime?

Comment: Is this a different question than your [other one from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317246/display-timer-that-works-out-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds-from-a-date-then-i/13318460#comment18168209_13318460)?

Comment: Actually, I think that it is (I thought that too, lol).  It is very similar though, and would use much of the same logic.

Comment: Apologies.. I need to work out the difference between the stored quitDate and todays date. I need to display 134 Days 23 hours 14 mins and 3 secs with it then updating in realtime. It is similar to the other question but slightly more clear.. I will upadte the other question.. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **NSDateComponents**

```
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];    

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]autorelease];

     NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

     NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:quitDate
                                              toDate:currentDate options:0];
     NSLog(@"Component Month:%d",[component month]);
     NSLog(@"Component Day:%d",[component day]);
     NSLog(@"Component Hour:%d",[component hour]);
     NSLog(@"Component Mins:%d",[component minute]);
```

Reference:[Difference between two NSDate objects -- Result also a NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562594/difference-between-two-nsdate-objects-result-also-a-nsdate)