# create a timer that would indicate days left to event starting today

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, time

I have a date that is retrieved from server in a Unix timestamp, and this is how i retrieve it and it's working fine :

```
double unixTimeStamp = [[date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row / 2] doubleValue];
NSTimeInterval _interval=unixTimeStamp;
NSDate *dateToFinal = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
_formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MMMM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz";
[_formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"timeZone"]] ];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMMM-yyyy"];
dateFinal=[_formatter stringFromDate:dateToFinal];


NSDateFormatter *_formatter2=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
_formatter2.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MMMM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz";
[_formatter2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"timeZone"]] ];
[_formatter2 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
dateTime =[_formatter2 stringFromDate:dateToFinal];
```

This date is loaded inside a tableViewCell, is there any way that i could create a field inside that custom cell , in which it will show me date left to event ? 
Exemple : 

 Date of event : 27 April 2014 7:00 pm , so this field should show up : 
2 Days 2 Hours left to event.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [display the difference in Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds with it then updating in realtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335281/display-the-difference-in-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds-with-it-then-updating)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is getting the timestamp (nr of the seconds from 1970) and convert it step by step.

```
int timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

- Begin from the seconds for 1 year
- If your timestamp is bigger than 1 year timestamp
- then raise nr of years and then make the difference between your
  timestamp with 1 year timestamp
- Else check the difference between 1 month and follow the same logic

There many libraries on GitHub to do that.

For example:

- [PrettyTimestamp](https://github.com/jonhocking/PrettyTimestamp)
- [SEHumanizedTimeDiff](https://github.com/sarperdag/SEHumanizedTimeDiff)

Check them out! :)